# Alternatives to site_url() and get_template_directory_uri()

Tags: urls, localhost, site-url

The problem I'm having is that my Wordpress is set up on localhost, but when I view the site from another computer,

```
"<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/image.png"
```

will return

```
"http://localhost/wp-content/themes/Theme/image.png"
```

which of course doesn't load. But it all works fine when the Wordpress is viewed locally, or put onto a web server and viewed from any computer.

Similar issue with `site_url()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use localhost for any particular reason?   The easiest fix for this will be to make those functions work correctly by putting a real hostname or ip address  into the site address field in WordPress settings.   Look in Settings > General Settings.